# JQuery Bootstrap Conflict in header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching for answer to this one to no avail. I have Bootstrap and then an infinite scroll using JQuery. The infinite scroll works fine, but I have the standard demo nav bar from bootstrap and the ul/lis are flashing up and then disappearing from the page so likely a conflict between jquery and bootstrap.

Here is the nav bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the javascript that no matter where I put it in the script (top or bottom) causes the issue:

```
<!-- <script src="../js/jquery-2.0.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="../js/jquery-ias.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`
```

Notice I have tried two versions of jquery too.

I dont know how to identify the conflict, what is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use $.noConflict();

[Reference url](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: why would this help when the only scripts shown are jQuery related?

Comment: On the likelihood this is a conflict, how would I go about identifying it?

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You have to give a better explanation of your solution.